# G++ Warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

I can't find the problem, anyone know solve?

Code

```
#include <algorithm>‎
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Warning

```
extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Some unvisible extra characters in the line?

Comment: Did you view your file in a hex editor to see if there are any control characters (such as `\r`) at the end of the line?

Comment: Wild bet: use `dos2unix` to clean up your Windows end-of-lines (`\r\n`) to Unix end-of-lines (`\n`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the code quoted above using `od -c` gives this output:

```
0000000    #   i   n   c   l   u   d   e       <   a   l   g   o   r   i
0000020    t   h   m   > 342 200 216  \n   i   n   t       m   a   i   n
0000040    (   i   n   t       a   r   g   c   ,       c   h   a   r   *
0000060        a   r   g   v   [   ]   )       {  \n                   r
0000100    e   t   u   r   n       0   ;  \n   }  \n
```

Note the bytes between the `>` and the `\n`: You probably want to get rid of them.

Comment: Wow I wouldn't have imagined SO would keep those bytes for you to dissect them. Good call.

Comment: I never imagined that this could happen. Thank you. Solved my problem

Comment: @syam - hooray for copy/paste!